# Can I Deploy a batch file with Group Policy to run as administrator?

Tags: domain-name-system, group-policy, batch-file

I have created a batch script which will block Facebook by amending the `hosts` file in this location `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

This is the contents of the batch file:

```
@echo off
echo 127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com >> C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
exit
```

I have tested this batch file on my local machine and it works however, it will only work when I run it as Administrator.

Is it possible to deploy this batch file to all computers on my network, running as administrator using Group Policy?

I am using Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can deploy batch files via Group Policy that will run under the context of Local System. A very common way of doing so is Computer Startup scripts. (As opposed to User Logon scripts.)

Also, this is probably the worst possible way imaginable of blocking Facebook.

[image: Computer Startup Script]

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770556.aspx

> Startup scripts are run under the Local System account, and they have the full rights that are associated with being able to run under the Local System account.

The Local System account is essentially even more powerful than Administrator.

Comment: Thanks,

The reason I want to use Group Policy to block facebook is because I need granularity. I want to only block it for particular users.

Comment: @pgunston this information would clarify the question.

Comment: I achieved my goal by using Symantec Endpoint Protection Management Server rather than using DNS.

Comment: I know I'm a year late, just wanted to iterate a bit on what Ryan said. This is the worst way of blocking Facebook because it relies on a lot and only works on IE. So if someone were to download another browser, that hosts file becomes pointless. However, if your network is locked down, everyone is domain user and downloads of Chrome are disabled, and you have all proxies blocked, then you should be fine, lol.

Comment: Jonas, that completely wrong. The DNS client on every operating system looks at the hosts file before running a query against the configured DNS servers. Every program running on the operating system, certainly all of the web browsers, use the operating system's DNS client to find hosts on the network. This is not just an IE fix, it will affect every program running on the machine that uses DNS normally.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change this to:

```
0.0.0.0 www.facebook.com
```

If you use the loopback address you'll have to wait for a timeout unless there is a local web server.

Comment: Are you sure about that? If you ping 127.0.0.1, it will respond immediately UNLESS that mechanism has been subverted somehow on your machine or your network.

Comment: You're listening for ping on localhost, but likely not for http traffic. Try again with http-ping or ping an unreachable host.

Comment: That might be a fair point. But if the objective is to block access to an objectionable website, why worry about a timeout? I have a ready answer, of course, which is that you get Facebook assets (tracking scripts, primarily) injected into other web pages all over the web, and a timeout accessing the facebook.com domain would impact the load time of every such page.

Comment: Why ask the question if you already know the answer? ;)

Comment: haha, well, one the one hand I don't care if they experience a timeout trying to access something I'm blocking. On the other hand... the law of unintended consequences.  ;)

Comment: Yes, even this site has Facebook assets. My responses here and elsewhere are based upon experience and research... those two tend to mitigate unintended consequences.

Comment: So... going back to the research issue. You will definitely experience a timeout trying to reach an IP address that doesn't respond immediately. Trying to reach a specific non-existent service on a live host, however, should result in an immediate rejection, as the host will explicitly refuse the connection. Unless the host is just dropping packets, of course, but it's unlikely that an edge device other than a firewall is doing that.

Comment: Test it and let me know... the answer may surprise you! :)

Comment: Informally (as tests go), I just tried 127.0.0.1 using a web browser, on my machine which is not currently configured as a development web server, and the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED result was immediate. To be fair, I've actually seen and done this in the past using hosts files that were intentionally full of objectionable (porn, gambling, etc.) dns names.

Comment: Immediate by your own sight, or 0ms?

Comment: Immediate enough that it wouldn't keep me awake at night if I needed granular user control without the budget for expensive new equipment?  ;-) Certainly much faster than the 2-second interval between tests that I see if I use http-ping. I don't feel that represents an accurate test. If I specify `-w 5` for a 5 second timeout, http-ping still bounces back every two seconds. I think that's just the timing they built into the program.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but what the heck. I'm not sure what's up with the naysayers. Pointing the objectionable domain to the local loopback address seems like a perfectly fine way to block access. It'll prevent DNS from returning the real address of the Facebook site, and if the user is not a local administrator, even if they know about the hosts file, which they probabaly don't, they won't have permissions to change it.

The problem I see with your approach is that if you got it running, you'll be appending that same line to your hosts file over and over again indefinitely.

If you're going to do this, you should have a script that looks for that line in the file, and only appends it if it doesn't already exist (and perhaps edits it if it doesn't say what you want it to).

Finally, running as the local SYSTEM account won't work if the script needs network access, unless you grant adequate permissions to the AD "Domain Computers" group and are prepared to do a little debugging.

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. There are a lot of "head scratching" answers here.

Comment: As there are everywhere, I suppose. And thank you for the welcome.  ;-)